# My PHP str_replace function isn't working with only one POST form

Tags: php, str-replace

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong - I have to sanitize the input. I've put in everything I can find to remove single quotes or apostrophes. This works in other circumstances, but not here. It returns a string where the single quotes or apostrophes are replaced by backslashes. (??!!)

function is:

```
function sanitize($data)
{

    return strtolower(str_replace(['’',';',"'",':',"&#039;","&#8217;",'&apos;','&quot;',' ','`','delete','update','drop','create'], '', htmlspecialchars($data) ));

}
```

So then if I submit into one form say "Joe's Diner", I get "joe\sdiner" returned.  I need "joesdiner".

I'm really not a programmer so I apologize if this is obvious.

Edit:

Maybe it's on the page?

```
 <form action="/test-breeding/" method="post">
First: <input type="text" name="first"> 
Second: <input type="text" name="second">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>

</form>
<br><br>

<?php

 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$first      = sanitize($_POST['first']);    
$second     = sanitize($_POST['second']);
}
```

Comment: [Works for me](https://3v4l.org/o1K3b)

Comment: Try adding a meta charset to the document `<meta charset="UTF-8" />`

Comment: Are you trying to sanitize for SQL insertion? If so, there are better ways to do this. Look at the MySQL manual for prepared statements: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: I know there's a better way. I am using snippets on wordpress and will do it better once I revamp things, but I just don't have the chops to do it all from scratch yet, and it has to work now. The same code works on other pages.  Just not this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's something with magic quotes, try adding `stripslashes`, like this:

```
$first = sanitize(stripslashes($_POST['first']));
```

Comment: Thank you. I added that after the sanitize(). Simple fix. But I promise I will use prepared statements soon!! Thanks for all your help everyone.